# How do I install Nvidia Optimus in 14.04?

Tags: nvidia, bumblebee

I've read dozens of news headlines last week, indicating that 14.04 has build-in Nvidia optimus support. How do I enable/install it?

Comment: I have the same question: Out of the box, if you press "super" and search for drivers and click "Additional Drivers", Ubuntu automatically search and point drivers available (I have a GT 630M). The problem is that it doesn't provide Optimus support, I already installed the "NVIDIA binary version 331.38 from nvidia-331 (proprietary, tested)" and tried to run a very GPU demanding FLAC Bluray hi10p (~18.3GB) file, and the video was "stopping" each 2~3 sec, it didn't run seamlessly. So, I followed the Bumblebee article from the [wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee) and tried the same file with

Comment: Please find Gladen's answer in this link. I'm sure it will answer your question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/472070/nvidia-proprietary-drivers-optimus-technology Also see this test of "Testing NVIDIA Optimus / DRI PRIME On Ubuntu 14.04":
http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=nvidia_prime_ubuntu1404&num=6

Answer (score 3):

I just installed nvidia-prime via terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-prime
```

A reboot and everything worked fine. I recommend to install Prime Indicator for a fast switch:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install prime-indicator
```

Log out and log in and voila.