# How to switch from bumblebee to nvidia-prime?

Tags: nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I have been using bumblebee in the past. Now I have read about nvidia-prime.

How can I install nvidia-prime? How do you configure it? Will it be in conflict with my current bumblebee install?

As a subquestion: What commands can I use to check what GPU is used and at what rates?

Also see [my other question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/466269/how-to-purge-and-reinstall-bumblebee-completely) on how to reinstall bumblebee.

Comment: Relevant, but not duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/449177/how-do-i-install-nvidia-optimus-in-14-04