# NVIDIA proprietary drivers - Optimus Technology

Tags: nvidia, 14.04, nvidia-optimus

I read from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/449177/how-do-i-install-nvidia-optimus-in-14-04%20/%22here%22) that Ubuntu 14.04 has native Optimus Technology support.Is this true or do I have to install the NVIDIA proprietary drivers?

If I have to install a proprietary driver which one is the correct for me?As you can see from the screenshot I get four options for proprietary drivers:

[image]

Comment: Note that the "native" support of nvidia-prime is not full support. That is, you have to turn the card on at log in (or startup?). IMO a better alternative is [bumblebee](http://bumblebee-project.org/), which allows you to have the card off generally (to save power), then turn it on manually for specific applications when needed. (FWIW you can also run bumblebee with the free nouveau drivers, rather than the proprietary nvidia ones, although I use the latter anyway.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, you do need to install the proprietary drivers to use this feature. You can just install the latest version of the drivers (which is the second to last one called nvidia-331-updates in the screenshot). When the drivers are installed, you should be able to access the Nvidia settings panel. In there, there is a tab called PRIME profiles, where you can switch between Intel (Power Saving) and NVIDIA (Performance).

The only downside is that you need to log out and back in in order to apply the changes.

Comment: Before I do anything can you please answer this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/472061/about-the-nvidia-proprietary-drivers

Comment: Sure. :) I'd answer it here, but it's a rather long answer. :P I posted an answer to your other question. Hopefully it's clear enough but if you have any other questions don't hesitate to ask!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable help on both of my questions! :)

Comment: No problem, glad I could help! :D

Answer (score 0):

Nvidia prime works far better than Bumblebee and unlike the former, to enable or disable the card just needs log out and login rather than a reboot. Also performance is far better with full HDMI out support with audio.